# How to express parsing logic in Parsec ParserT monad

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads, parsec

I was working on "Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 hours" to learn Haskell and I've run into a problem I don't really understand. It's for question 2 from the exercises at the bottom of [this section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing#Return_Values).

The task is to rewrite

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
parseString :: Parser LispVal
parseString = do
                char '"'
                x <- many (noneOf "\"")
                char '"'
                return $ String x
```

such that quotation marks which are properly escaped (e.g. in "This sentence \" is nonsense") get accepted by the parser.

In an imperative language I might write something like this (roughly pythonic pseudocode):

```
def parseString(input): 
  if input[0] != "\"" or input[len(input)-1] != "\"":
    return error
  input = input[1:len(input) - 1] # slice off quotation marks  
  output = "" # This is the 'zero' that accumulates over the following loop
  # If there is a '"' in our string we want to make sure the previous char
  # was '\'  

  for n in range(len(input)):
    if input[n] == "\"":
      try:
        if input[n - 1] != "\\":
          return error
      catch IndexOutOfBoundsError:
        return error
    output += input[n]
  return output
```

I've been looking at the [docs for Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html) and I just can't figure out how to work this as a monadic expression.

I got to this:

```
parseString :: Parser LispVal
parseString = do
                char '"'
                regular <- try $ many (noneOf "\"\\")
                quote <- string "\\\""
                char '"'
                return $ String $ regular ++ quote
```

But this only works for one quotation mark and it has to be at the very end of the string--I can't think of a functional expression that does the work that my loops and if-statements do in the imperative pseudocode.

I appreciate you taking your time to read this and give me advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
dq :: Char
dq = '"'

parseString :: Parser Val
parseString = do
  _ <- char dq
  x <- many ((char '\\' >> escapes) <|> noneOf [dq])
  _ <- char dq
  return $ String x
    where
      escapes = dq <$ char dq
            <|> '\n' <$ char 'n'
            <|> '\r' <$ char 'r'
            <|> '\t' <$ char 't'
            <|> '\\' <$ char '\\'
```

Comment: An aside: `x >> return a` is `a <$ x`.

Comment: Thank you! I worked through the type signatures and documentation to see why `x >> return a` is `a <$ x`. Is there a reason why the latter expression is preferred over the former here?

And is there a reason why `_ <- char dq` is preferred over `char dq`?
(edited)

Comment: The expression with `<$` is shorter. As for `_ <- char dq`, I had copied that code from when I did Scheme in 48 Hours. It makes it clear that the value of `char dq` isn't used. Otherwise you'd get a compiler warning (at least with `-Wall`).

Comment: @lachrimae For any type obeying the monad laws, `x >> return a` and `a <$ x` must be equal, so it doesn't matter at all in terms of semantics - obviously the latter saves you typing "return" *n* times.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to define a string literal as a starting quote + many valid characters + an ending quote where a "valid character" is either a an escape sequence or non-quote.

So there is a one line change to `parseString`:

```
parseString = do char '"'
                 x <- many validChar
                 char '"'
                 return $ String x
```

and we add the definitions:

```
validChar = try escapeSequence <|> satisfy ( /= '"' )
escapeSequence = do { char '\\'; anyChar }
```

`escapeSequence` may be refined to allow a limited set of escape sequences.